# convert list to map using java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an arraylist

```
List<Integer> h = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

I want to filter even numbers and then store them in a map with a key, which is a unique number starting from 1 and value being the filtered value using java8

output  `1-2 2-4 3-6`

I will be using filter and `Collectors.toMap()` in collect

```
Map<Integer,Integer> j =  h.stream().filter(fe->fe%2==0).collect(Collectors.toMap(?,?));
```

what will be the output?

Comment: I don't understand how the map should be filled. Why it's not 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 ?

Comment: Yes but at the end there is `3-6` which are not pair number. That's why i don't understand

Comment: oh yes ! thanks you

Comment: You can try something like this for your stream, `h.stream().forEach(fe-> {if (fe % 2 == 0) { map.computeIfAbsent(map.size()+1,i->fe); }});`

Comment: somthig like this: `int[] counter = new int[1]{1}; ....collect(Collectors.toMap(counter[0]++, value -> value))`

Comment: @user16320675 because you cant change variables inside of lambdas. `new int[]{1}` yes, i'm using kotlin right now so don't remember correct syntax

Comment: the ley will be the unique sequence number starting from 1 which will increment by 1 like 1,2,3,4,5.... and value is the even numbers present in the list which is been iterated so for example for 1,2,3,4,5,6 it will be 2,4,6..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that

```
List<Integer> h = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
AtomicInteger f = new AtomicInteger(0);
Map<Integer,Integer> j = h.stream()
                    .filter(fe-> fe%2==0) 
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(fs -> f.incrementAndGet(), fs -> fs));
```

Comment: ah  test this
List<Integer> h = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        AtomicInteger f = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Map<Integer,Integer> j =  h.stream()
                .filter(fe-> fe%2==0)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(fs -> f.incrementAndGet(), fs -> fs));

Comment: I've just updated the answer, if it is what you are searching for please validate my answer

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, and maybe it's not the best Idea, but if you have to use Collectors.toMap, maybe the following could work

```
Map<Integer,Integer> j =  h.stream()
                           .filter(fe->fe%2==0)
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(i ->{
            return h.stream().filter(fe->fe%2==0).collect(Collectors.toList()).indexOf(i);
        },Function.identity()));
```